# How do i recreate a trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

i use the statement `drop trigger if exist TRIGGER` in sqlite but sql server doesnt like the if statement. (i guess exist is the offending word). I do this right next to my create trigger statement because i want to drop older triggers with the same name so i can replace it with this new one.

How do i do this in SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the existence of a specific Trigger like so.

```
IF EXISTS
(
select name
from sys.objects
where type='TR' and name ='Trigger Name'
)
BEGIN

--Add your Trigger create code here

END
```

Answer (score 4):

in SQL Server Management Studio (and, I think in Query Analyzer) right-click the trigger in the explorer, and choose the Script-as option, choose 'Drop Trigger' in clipboard, and SSMS will create the T-SQL syntax for you to drop that trigger.

Sorry I haven't given you T-SQL you can copy and paste, but this way you'll know how to do it for next time.

Comment: This is how I learned many of my scripting tactics. Realizing how poor the code generated by Enterprise Manager (and SSMS) really is is how I learned much of the rest.

Comment: unfortunately there are yet to be solved issue preventing me from running it on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

I find this to be a more compact SQL Server equivalent to MySQL's `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` syntax:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('XXXX', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like:

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.xxx'), 'isTrigger') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.xxx
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.xxx [etc]
```

replacing xxx with your trigger name (and dbo with the relevant schema, if necessary).

Alternatively, you could just use

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.xxx [etc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2016 this syntax is also [supported by Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name`